# get value from selected input

Tags: jquery, advanced-custom-fields, meta-value, input

here is my situation,

I have different input, each of them them having a

```
<input id="q1a2" type="radio" name="q1" value="1" tabindex="-1">
<input id="q2a1" type="radio" name="q2" value="3" tabindex="-1">
```

etc

those value are being taken from an Advanced custom field like:

```
<?php if( have_rows('answer_three') ): ?>

    <?php while( have_rows('answer_three') ): the_row(); ?>

    <input id="<?php echo 'q' . $i . 'a3' ?>" type="radio" name="<?php echo 'q' . $i ?>" value="<?php the_sub_field('score_three');  ?>">
    <label value="<?php the_sub_field('score_three');  ?>" for="<?php echo 'q' . $i . 'a3'   ?>">
    <?php the_sub_field('new_answer_three');  ?></label>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

when an input is selected ( "checked")

The html look like:

```
body.page-template-page-test section.questions input:checked + label
```

What I am trying to achieve is to display the value of the input checked only.

How is this possible to achieve

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Where do you want to display the value?

Comment: in another <div class="score"> </div>

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know how many `input` type of radios and checkboxes you have, but this should get you want you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function() {
        // get the value
        var newValue = $(this).val();

        // Update the div.score
        $('div.score').text(newValue);
    });
});
```

PS: Your radio input need to have the same name, if you do not want more than one radio to be selected.

See [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwZMgB)